# when opening an html file on browser, I see the source code

Tags: html

I am trying to open a basic "hello world" html file on a browser (chrome/explorer). However, the browser displays the code itself rather than the expected result. What can be the problem?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I've just written this code in a text file called helloWorld.html and opened it with the browser. 
Thanks!

Comment: whats your code? Can you paste it here

Comment: Maybe your file extension is not ".htm" or ".html"?

Comment: are you sure Windows (assuming you're on Windows) is not hiding file extension and your file is not called index.html.txt but showing index.html?

Comment: If your explorer isn't showing known file extensions, you've probably accidentally saved it as a .html.txt file. When saving, change the type to "All known extensions" (if using Notepad, for example), then save it.

Comment: What is the url in the browser?

Comment: Thank you all, it's really saved as an .html.txt... But how do I change it? I don't see an "all known extensions" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html is fine my bet is you saved it as index.html.txt(on accident)
Could you please check for that :)

Comment: Easy, Assuming you have the file selected in your explorer press in the left top organise, map and search options, display, and then look for something like hide well known extensions uncheck that one and you should see the txt extension on all html files :) my windows is dutch btw so i could be partially wrong. After that i suppose i dont have to explain how to change file names :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a text editor (such as Notepad), Save As... and save it with the formatting as filename.html. If you don't specify the file type when saving, Notepad will default to adding the text file extension.